# How to compare the below specified table and assign the status?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a database table for "orders"

order id, userid, order_status..

I need to check whether the user has completed the order status for at least one product so that I can approve the user to be active participant in my referral system. The user can purchase many products and have many orders, but I need to know whether he as completed at least one complete successful order.

Then I can compare the status and assign him as active.

```
My table goes like this

order_id   user_id order_status
1           2       completed
2           2       pending
3           3       pending
4           4       completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do something very simple like;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_id, 
  user_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE order_status='completed') "good standing"
FROM orders;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/714d0/3).

Comment: Thank you and its awesome on Fiddle example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Will be "true", if one exists. No rows are returned if it doesn't exist.

```
SELECT true WHERE user_id=:user_id AND order_status=completed LIMIT 1
```